# How to list files and directories of a mount point

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Given a mountpoint such as /dev/sda1 how can I list the contents of this file system using shell script. My objective is to delete the oldest file in this drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/dev/sda1` is a block device. It may contain a file system. When mounted, that file system may be available at some mount point like `/home`, `/`, and within that file system, some directories may in turn be some mount points for other file systems (may they be in other block devices, or virtual ones like `/proc`, or network ones...).

If `/dev/sda1` is mounted on `/`, to remove the oldest (in terms of last modification time) *regular* file, on a recent GNU system, you can do:

```
find / -xdev -type f -printf '%T@:%p\0' |
   sort -zn |
   sed -z 's/[^:]*://;q' |
   xargs -r0p rm -f
```

The `-xdev` flag tells `find` to stick to one file system, that is, not to descend into other file systems mounted within `/` in this case.

Note that other file systems may hide files on the file system of their mount point. For instance, if `/dev/sda1` is mounted on `/` but contains a `/home/some-old-file` and `/dev/sda2` is mounted on `/home`, `/home/some-old-file` will not be accessible.

On Linux at least, you can work around that by bind-mounting `/` in another directory:

```
mount --bind / /mnt/side-access-to-root
```

Then all the files in the file system mounted at `/` will be available through `/mnt/side-access-to-root`.

Then, you can ommit the `-xdev` and you could use `zsh` globbing to remove the oldest file:

```
rm -i /mnt/side-access-to-root/**/*(D.Om[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

/dev/sda1 is not a mount point, it points to your partition on your drive.

To mount your disk use

```
mount -t vfat(OR THE TYPE OF YOUR DRIVE) /dev/sda1 /path/to/mount/to
```

Then, to list all files in a path, you can use

```
ls
```

However, to delete all files older then X days, you can use:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +x -exec rm {} \;
```